# Ajax validator function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have to validate my form which does a scheduling. I used ajax and php to do a query and search that time - that was choosen in a select - in the database. If there's one row saved, it returns 1 (or false), if doesn't, returns 0 (or true). Anyway, in the function callback, even it's true, the validate error appears, as if it had a real error. Printing the value, we see the value, but i dont know why it shows the error. I've tried everything, and nowhere i found the answer for this.

The js file: alteraDiv.js

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('confereDia', function(value){
        alert("entrou no método");
        if (conf(value) == '0'){
            alert("entrou no if");
            return true;
        }else{
            alert("entrou no else");
            return false;
        }

    }); 

    var verifica;
    function setVerifica(x){
        verifica = x;
    }

    function conf(value){
        $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: 'confereDia.php?horarioInicial='+value,
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("entrou no success");
                    setVerifica(data);
                    alert("value:"+value);  
                    return verifica;
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert("ERROR. Dados: " + data);  
                }                       
        });

    }
```

The php file: confereDia.php

```
   $horarioInicial = $_GET["horarioInicial"];
$query = "SELECT idAgendamento FROM agendamento WHERE horarioInicial = '$horarioInicial'";
$results = mysql_query($query);   
if (mysql_num_rows($results) == 0) {
    echo '0';  //good to register
} else {
    echo '1'; //already registered
}
```

There are more codes in the files, but i think these are necessary for you understand and help me.. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Have you done basic debugging, like `console.log(value)` to see what's realy coming back from the php script? the query might be ok, but ANY output from php (e.g. a warning/error) would become part of the output and making your 1/0 be "not-1" or "not-0"

Comment: I'll sure try what you've said, Marc B.